# jQuery - Execute a function on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a class on my navigation bar when a page is loaded.

Here's my try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('index.php').load(function(){
        $("#etusivu").addClass("selected");
        $("#quartz").removeClass("selected");
        $("#raikastimet").removeClass("selected");
        $("#sisusta").removeClass("selected");
        $("#teipit").removeClass("selected");
        $("#vaimennusmatot").removeClass("selected");
    });

    $('quartz.php').load(function(){

        $("#etusivu").removeClass("selected");
        $("#quartz").addClass("selected");
        $("#raikastimet").removeClass("selected");
        $("#sisusta").removeClass("selected");
        $("#teipit").removeClass("selected");
        $("#vaimennusmatot").removeClass("selected");
    });

    $('raikastimet.php').load(function(){

        $("#etusivu").removeClass("selected");
        $("#quartz").removeClass("selected");
        $("#raikastimet").addClass("selected");
        $("#sisusta").removeClass("selected");
        $("#teipit").removeClass("selected");
        $("#vaimennusmatot").removeClass("selected");
    });

    $('sisusta.php').load(function(){

        $("#etusivu").removeClass("selected");
        $("#quartz").removeClass("selected");
        $("#raikastimet").removeClass("selected");
        $("#sisusta").addClass("selected");
        $("#teipit").removeClass("selected");
        $("#vaimennusmatot").removeClass("selected");
    });

    $('teipit.php').load(function(){

        $("#etusivu").removeClass("selected");
        $("#quartz").removeClass("selected");
        $("#raikastimet").removeClass("selected");
        $("#sisusta").removeClass("selected");
        $("#teipit").addClass("selected");
        $("#vaimennusmatot").removeClass("selected");
    });

    $('vaimennusmatot.php').load(function(){

        $("#etusivu").removeClass("selected");
        $("#quartz").removeClass("selected");
        $("#raikastimet").removeClass("selected");
        $("#sisusta").removeClass("selected");
        $("#teipit").removeClass("selected");
        $("#vaimennusmatot").addClass("selected");
    });

});
```

So I'm trying to add `class="selected"` when user clicks a link on navigation, and browser loads a new page. But this isn't working.

Here's the navigation:

```
<ul id="navigation">';
        <li id="etusivu"><a href="index.php">Etusivu</a></li>
        <li id="quartz"><a href="quartz.php">Quartz-kalvot</a></li>
        <li id="raikastimet"><a href="raikastimet.php">Raikastimet</a></li>
        <li id="sisusta"><a href="sisusta.php">Sisusta</a></li>
        <li id="teipit"><a href="teipit.php">Teipit</a></li>
        <li id="vaimennusmatot"><a href="vaimennusmatot.php">Vaimennusmatot</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the correct usage of `load` method.

> .load( url [, data] [, complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#navigation a').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault(); // prevents the default action of the event
     $(this).parent().addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
     var url = this.href;
     $('#whereToLoad').load(url)
  })

});
```

- [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)
- [sublings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)
- [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: It's the correct syntax for the *other* [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) function. Usage is still wrong though.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yes, `load` event.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen Yes, I had missed a `{` after function.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, this loads the new content to a div via ajax? Perfect, I actually tried to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that you place within

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    ...

});
```

... will be executed immediately at DOMReady for every document that contains that piece of code. If you want to change the selected-class at that point, you could do something like:

```
$('#navigation .selected').removeClass('selected'); // remove 'selected' class from all li's that have it
$('#id-of-current-page').addClass('selected');
```

Now, to find out which the current element is, you could for instance inspect `location.href`. However, seeing asyou're using PHP, I would really recommend just adding the selected class in the rendered HTML to begin with.

What your code currently does is to fetch all those pages through AJAX requests immediately as the page loads, and then add and remove the selected class a lot for every response.